# Describing complex return type of the method

Tags: python, python-3.x, strong-typing

I'm trying to define return type of the method in Python (3.8.9).
Ideally, return type should be `list` of `tuple` of `int`. My first natural solution, as I came from strongly typed world, was `def .... -> list(tuple(int,int))`.

Unfortunately this doesn't work and bring runtime exception

> tuple expected at most 1 argument, got 2

As per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) section *Type Alias* defining type like `list[int]` or `tuple[int]` should work but in my code I'm getting same error even if C/P code from documentation.

Is type hint feature is version specific? What am I missing?

Comment: You need Python >= 3.9 to use built-in container types in type annotations.  On older versions you must use `typing.List`, `typing.Tuple`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using round brackets, while the documentation specifies square brackets.

Try this, for example:

```
def fn() -> list[tuple[int, int]]:
    return [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Or, if you are using Python versions older than 3.9, try this:

```
from typing import List, Tuple


def fn() -> List[Tuple[int, int]]:
    return [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: I've tried this approach also and I'm getting `Subscript for class "list" will generate runtime exception; enclose type annotation in quotes` error. As @0x5453 mentioned, maybe it's actually issue in the version.